# Pass data from a callback closure to mpsc producer in Rust

Tags: rust

I have the following code. I create an mpsc channel and the goal is to pass the sender to the closure and that closure will be registered as a callback with a library and later the data from callback sent to the channel for consumption elsewhere.

```
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::sync::mpsc::Sender;
use std::thread;

fn init(sender: Sender<&[u8]>) {
    let handle_event = |x:i32, data:&[u8]| {
        sender.send(data).unwrap();
        };
    //handle will be registered as callback with some library
    //and used later in this thread
    sender.send("Callback registered".as_bytes()).unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    let (producer, bottle) = channel();
    let child = thread::spawn(move ||init(producer));
    for message in bottle {
        //process data
    }
    let res = child.join();
    
}
```

But I get the following error on compilation:

```
error[E0312]: lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content...
 --> src/main.rs:7:21
  |
7 |         sender.send(data).unwrap();
  |                     ^^^^
  |
note: ...the reference is valid for the anonymous lifetime defined on the function body at 5:24...
 --> src/main.rs:5:24
  |
5 | fn init(sender: Sender<&[u8]>) {
  |                        ^^^^^
note: ...but the borrowed content is only valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 6:24
 --> src/main.rs:6:24
  |
6 |       let handle_event = |x:i32, data:&[u8]| {
  |  ________________________^
7 | |         sender.send(data).unwrap();
8 | |         };
  | |_________^
```

How can I get around this? The line where I register the callback also throws the this error.

```
explicit lifetime required in the type of `sender`
   |
64 |         .sample_cb(handle_event)
   |          ^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'static` required
```

The callback should be of this trait

```
pub trait SampleCb: FnMut(i32, &[u8]) + 'static {}
```

I'm not sure if the second error is caused due to the first error, as the first error happens regardless of registering it as callback as can be seen [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1eafc2334b8ddc1e665a2a098e2cc6b8)

Answer (score 0):

To fix your first error, simply name the lifetime on the `Sender<&[u8]>` then add that lifetime to the argument of `handle_event`:

```rust
// name the lifetime 'a
fn init<'a>(sender: Sender<&'a [u8]>) {
    // take in &'a [u8] instead of &[u8]
    let handle_event = |x: i32, data: &'a [u8]| {
        sender.send(data).unwrap();
    };
    // ...
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=23aed79129fd1136d202e3d3e0a3ae25)

Comment: Does this mean that data is to be kept alive for the lifetime of the sender? Logically it should be dropped as soon as the receiver is done processing it.

Comment: @SamThomas The typesystem doesn't know when the receiver is going to use the data. The receiver could wait any amount of time before consuming it, so the data needs to be valid for the lifetime of the sender.

Comment: Understood.Since the sender will live for ever, does this mean all “data” from all the call backs will live for ever? Will this be a memory explosion? Do I have to manually drop this in the receiver ?

Comment: If you want to free memory up, I'd suggest using owned data types that the receiver can drop, such as sending `Vec<[u8]>`s instead of `&[u8]`s. If you have a lot of slices that you don't want to allocate a `Vec` for, you could also consider a [`Cow<[u8]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) which would allow you to send both slices and Vecs.

Comment: So am I right about the memory explosion for the above method of associating data's lifetime with the sender? Because the callback will be invoked many times.

Comment: Also I did think about Vec<u8> but didn't know about Cow. Thanks for letting me know about it. Unfortunately, ``Cow::from(data)`` has the same lifetime problem. Maybe I am using it wrong? I would definitely love to avoid allocations if possible.

Comment: Here's a version using `Cow`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b0d78195fb412db731052b150d82d2de

Comment: Does this also mean that cow and hence the borrowed value loves as long as the sender?

Comment: `Cow` has 2 variants: `Borrowed` and `Owned`. If it's `Borrowed`, which you might use for things like bytestring literals, then it'll live as long as the sender. If it's `Owned`, it'll be dropped once the receiver drops it. If you don't need `Borrowed`, use `Vec<u8>` instead.

Comment: Cool, can you edit your answer talking about memory explosions with respect to assigning same lifetime as sender and hence suggest to use vector for this scenario? I’ll accept the answer 